# БД для проекта, sqlite или postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

Есть приложение на django + vue, бд хранит в себе тексты которые отображаются пользователю по запросу, текстов не очень много (меньше 100) и они не очень большие (школьные задачи), клиент отправляет post запросы с ответами, которые не хранятся в бд, просто проверяются и возвращается результат проверки, авторизации тоже никакой нет. Хватит ли для такого проекта sqlite?

Comment: Для такого размера хватит возможностей любой БД. Можно даже просто в JSON файл всё записать и БД не использовать. С SQLite будут скорее проблемы в некоторой ограниченности фичей. Например нельзя из таблицы удалить колонку  в одно действие. Надо создавать временную таблицу и через неё в новую таблицу данные перегонять.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо большое! а если я захочу хранить ответы, мне уже без постгрес не обойтись будет?

Comment: Обойтись можно. Если вас смущает Lite в смысле хранения больших объёмов данных - то это не так. В SQLlite можно десятки терабайт хранить. Lite это скорее про функционал, типа описанного выше удаления колонки из таблицы.

Comment: у меня не большой опыт разработки, но встречался с проблемой использования SQLite в django проектах, например из-за того что SQLite хранится в файле могут быть проблемы с работой на эфемерных хранилищах, например Heroku, то есть читать из БД можно, а записать не получится, так как  сессия хранилища закроется и все файлы откатятся в первоначальное состояние. Так же встречал проблему с многопоточным доступом к курсору БД, который не поддерживается в SQLite. Но еще раз оговорюсь, что опыт разработки у меня весьма скромный)

Comment: Используйте любую БД, для таких задач подойдет всё